# book recommendation for Euclidean geometry without coordinates or any modern math (math that has been discovered after the 16th century.)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, book-recommendation

I want to learn Euclidean geometry But I always find books about it that use coordinates and even some linear algebra and other stuff that was discovered thousands of years after geometry but I want to learn how many ideas of geometry has been discovered and evolved for thousands of years without any modern techniques like analytical geometry or linear algebra or integration ...etc.

I also want 3 types of books

1-and the more important books that cover many of theorems of Euclid geometry before Desecrates without coordinates or any modern math like How Archimedes found out the volume of solids like sphere and area of parabolas without integration etc.. .

2-books that are more focus on problem solving and hard and practise questions like IMO training books

3- books that cover more advanced topics in Euclidean geometry after Desecrates that use modern methods.

Comment: What about reading Euclid's *The Elements*?!!

Comment: @Ted Shifrin interesting,is this book really written by Euclid ? but I am worried because this book is too old that id doesn't has many theorems that has been discovered hundreds of years after Euclid

Comment: Yes, Euclid really wrote it. You don't have to read it in Greek; there are well-done English translations with lots of commentary and elaboration. The standard one is by Sir Thomas Heath. I would start there and not worry so much about what came between Euclid and Descartes.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I just checked the book and it seems great and I will read it  thank you for your suggestion but I am still worried about "what came between Euclid and Descartes" but for now I will read the entire book and maybe in the future if I want to learn more about geometry I will re-ask this question

Comment: In all seriousness, I had a much better than average high school geometry course (back in 1968) and we never got past Euclid (except for a tiny bit of analytic geometry using cartesian coordinates); and we certainly did far less 3D geometry than Euclid does.

Comment: @TedShifrin It seems to me that OP is interested in “advanced” Euclidean geometry, similar to what I do, which is why they ask about results and theorems derived *after* Euclid

Comment: @冥王 Hades
  is there a book that you would recommend to me?

Comment: @pie Honestly it depends entirely on your current level and how far you wish to go in Euclidean geometry. You can definitely read The Elements as Ted recommended and in fact I also recommend that you start with it. But beyond that, it just depends on how far you wish to go. You can certainly find books on advanced Euclidean geometry used for IMO preparation containing difficult problems. If you’d like, I can link several threads that answer *that* question with specific recommendations

Comment: @冥王Hades that would be great and very helpful , but I am worried that IMO books would focus more on the hard problems and problem solving skills rather than the the theorems itself but anyway still i need a source for problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fond of [Lachlan, *Modern Pure Geometry*, (1893)](https://archive.org/details/cu31924059156616/page/n9/mode/2up).

Lots more where that came from - geometry textbooks from the period 1825-1925 - most of them on [archive.org](https://archive.org/).  Some are mentioned in Lachlan's introduction, so you can search for them in archive.org.

For something completely different, take a look at the opinionated and idiosyncratic [Coolidge, *A History of the Conic Sections and Quadric Surfaces* (1945)](https://archive.org/details/historyofconicse0000cool/mode/2up). Since you ask about Archimedes, the book mentions [J.I. Heath, *The Works Of Archimedes* (1817)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.133665/page/n9/mode/2up) which contains translations of Archimedes' works [*On The Sphere and Cylinder*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.133665/page/n181/mode/2up) and [*Quadrature of the Parabola*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.133665/page/n411/mode/2up).  See also T.L. Heath's 1896 translation of [Apollonius, *Conic Sections*, pgs lviii-lxvii](https://archive.org/details/treatiseonconics00apolrich/page/n65/mode/2up)

Comment: that would be great if you can recommend more books , but why nobody cares about geometry after 1925 it seems that we forgot about it

Comment: @pie,  Lots of people cared after 1925, but it became less mainstream and by the 1970's had disappeared from most curricula.  But there has been a revival in recent decades.  I've added a few more recommendations.

Comment: how do you know about these books?
and how do you search for good books

Comment: @pie Good question, no easy answer.  Usually I don't look for "good books".  Rather I'm searching for a specific answer to a problem or topic that I'm interested in. 30 years ago it would be in a math library, browsing the books, periodicals and card catalogs.  Now it's the internet. For me, specific questions that catch my curiosity are the keys to learning a larger topic.  And along the way you find books and papers that are worth reading all the way through.  Many disciplines are like this, but especially math, both learning and researching: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10548173

Answer (score 4):

The book series you are looking for is Kiselev's Geometry. These are small yet beautifully bound hardcover books that cover planimetry and stereometry.

Kiselev's page can be found on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?i=stripbooks&rh=p_27%3AA.+P.+Kiselev&s=relevancerank&text=A.+P.+Kiselev&ref=dp_byline_sr_book_1)which contains both books. I do not recommend buying them there because their price is way off the mark. I have both copies and I don't believe I paid more than $\$30$ for each book. In fact, I may have paid less.

Comment: These are great books! I found them online but  they seem very small and don't contain much geometry

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can have a look to the book of Akopyan. It is free on his webpage, but you can also buy it via Amazon.. This book contains no coordinates, but no text neither. You have plenty of theorems explained by a picture, and you have to prove it by yourself..

https://users.mccme.ru/akopyan/papers/EnGeoFigures.pdf

Comment: A charismatic book!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to study Euclidean geometry, why not get hold of Euclid’s *Elements*? Old and still good, inexpensive and easy to find. He doesn’t tell you how to find things out, but rather gives you an orderly, step-by-step, and dramatic demonstration of results.

Comment: Great suggestion! I will begin with his book but what about all the geometry between Euclid and Descartes?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll recommend the book reviewed in this video https://youtu.be/1B2BtvWsz-M

Comment: شكله بسيط جدا و لكن اللي انا عايزة كتب في المواضيع المتقدمة في الهندسة

Comment: لربما يجب عليك الاطلاع على هذا الكتاب https://www.academia.edu/86234543/PROBLEMS_IN_PLANE_AND_SOLID_GEOMETRY_v_1_Plane_Geometry_Viktor_Prasolov_translated_and_edited_by_Dimitry_Leites